# Convert an EPS file with transparency and CMYK colorspace to PNG with ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, png, eps

I would like to convert an EPS vector graphics (CMYK) file to PNG, with PHP ImageMagick, keeping the transparency.
I can easily do it in command line with the following command:

```
 convert -colorspace RGB test_file_with_transaprency.eps PNG32:result_with_transparency.png
```

But my attempts with the PHP version fail, producing white background.
I got it working with SVG though, so this works when converting from SVG.

```
        $image = new \Imagick();
        $image->setBackgroundColor(new \ImagickPixel('transparent'));
        $image->readImageBlob(file_get_contents($sourceImagePath));
        $image->writeImage('./vector_test/eps_to_png_test.png');
```

Comment: The PostScript language doesn't support transparency, so you cannot 'keep' the transparency, because thre is none there. I suspect what you mean is that you want the unmarked areas to be transparent, instead of white, which is what they 'should' be when rendered using the PostScript rules. Ghostscript's PNG output devices will do that, so you might be better using Ghostscript directly rather than vis ImageMagick.

Comment: In Imagemagick you can convert your EPS file with transparency to PNG, but you need to convert it from CMYK to RGB. That would be done as you have written, but you should use -colorspace sRGB not RGB, unless you are on a very old version of Imagemagick. However, the EPS/PS/PDF entries in the delegates.xml file need to use sDEVICE=pngalpha and not pnmraw. With PHP Imagick, you often need to specify the full path to gs (ghostscript) in your delegates.xml file entries that use ghostscript, since PHP does not use the same $PATH as the shell.